# Using only object id and lastUpdate for diff on useEffect in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-effect

I have a large and deep object which I render using a React functional component (composed of child components). I also use Redux in the project which interacts with an API. To keep the app fast, I keep a local copy of the object in the component state and dispatch changes when occurred. The objects can also change in different parts of the app.

Each time the object changes in Redux its lastUpdated field is updated with the current time (epoch) by Redux. So instead of doing a deep (and expensive) diff on the whole object it is sufficient to compare the object id (in case the component has to display a different object) and the lastUpdated value (in case the object itself got changed).

This is what my functional component looks like:

```
interface Item {
   id: string
   lastUpdated: number
   // more fields here
}
interface Props {
   item : Item
}
export default function ItemPage(props: Props){

   const [displayItem, setDisplayItem] = useState<Item>(props.item)

   useEffect(() => {
      if (props.item.id !== display.item.id && props.item.lastUpdated !== displayItem.lastUpdated){
         setDisplayItem(props.item)
         // ... some logic comes here
      }
   }, [props.item.id, props.item.lastUpdated])

   return (
      // ... render code here
   )
}
```

This code cause the following error:

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'item.id' and
> 'item.lastUpdated'. Either include them or remove the dependency array
> react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I have disable the error with:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Questions:

1. Is it safe to to disable the error as I know the logic of my Redux (and use the more efficient diff)? Is there a better solution?
2. Is it safe to completely remove the useEffect array as I make the id/lastUpdated diff myself?

Note: I am not looking for the general "do not disable as it will come back to bite you ..." answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need `React.memo` with second argument isEqual. Is equal works like `shouldComponentUpdate`. Read reactjs docs more about React.memo

UPDATE:

I've added [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-memo-ho41o?file=/src/Item.tsx:278-522) as example

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you show in code how it would work?